# Changing LeadController method to read user_id label instead of Value

Tags: laravel, routes, controller

I have this code of my CRM which is working fine, but the drop-down menu is showing the user ID instead of the User name.

Now, I want it to show the username instead:

```php
// LeadController code:

public function massUpdateSalesperson()
{
    $data = request()->all();

    foreach ($data['rows'] as $leadId) {
        $lead = $this->leadRepository->find($leadId);
        $lead->update(['user_id' => Arr::get($data, 'value.value')]);

        Event::dispatch('lead.update.before', $leadId);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'message' => trans('admin::app.response.update-success', ['name' => trans('admin::app.leads.title')])
    ]);
}
```

and this DataGrid Code:

```php
$this->addMassAction([
    'type'    => 'update',
    'label'   => trans('admin::app.datagrid.update_salesperson'),
    'action'  => route('admin.leads.mass_update_salesperson'),
    'method'  => 'PUT',
    'options' =>$this->getUserDropdownOptions(),
]);
```

When I do following changes it updates the lead by value to "Null" instead of updating with the new Sales Person.

LeadDataGrid Code:

```php
public function prepareMassActions()
{

    $users = User::all();
    $UserName = [];
    
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $UserName[$user['name']] = $user['id'];
    }

     $this->addMassAction([
        'type'    => 'update',
        'label'   => trans('admin::app.datagrid.update_salesperson'),
        'action'  => route('admin.leads.mass_update_salesperson'),
        'method'  => 'PUT',
        'options' => $UserName,
    ]);
}
```

LeadController Code:

```php
public function massUpdateSalesperson()
{
    $data = request()->all();

    foreach ($data['rows'] as $leadId) {
        $lead = $this->leadRepository->find($leadId);
        $lead->update(['user_id' => Arr::get($data, 'value.value')]);
        Event::dispatch('lead.update.before', $leadId);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'message' => trans('admin::app.response.update-success', ['name' => trans('admin::app.leads.title')])
    ]);
}
```

Noting that when I change this change the value.value to value.label I still get the same thing.

and here's the getUserDropdownOptions() code

```
public function getUserDropdownOptions(): array
{
    $options = app(\Webkul\User\Repositories\UserRepository::class)
        ->get(['id as value', 'name as label'])
        ->map(function ($item, $key) {
            $item->disabled = false;
            $item->selected = false;
            return $item;
        })
        ->pluck('label', 'value') // Modify this line to pluck the name as 'label' and the ID as 'value'
        ->toArray();

    return [
        [
            'label'    => __('admin::app.common.select-users'),
            'value'    => '',
            'disabled' => true,
            'selected' => true,
        ],
        ...$options
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using [bagisto/bagisto](https://github.com/bagisto/bagisto) package. Your `pluck()` arguments need to be inverse. It should be like this :

```
public function getUserDropdownOptions(): array
{
    $options = app(\Webkul\User\Repositories\UserRepository::class)
        ->get(['id as value', 'name as label'])
        ->map(function ($item, $key) {
            $item->disabled = false;
            $item->selected = false;
            return $item;
        })
        ->pluck('value', 'label') // Modify this line to pluck the name as 'label' and the ID as 'value'
        ->toArray();

    return [
        'label'    => __('admin::app.common.select-users'),
        'value'    => '',
        'disabled' => true,
        'selected' => true,
        'options' => $options
    ];
}
```

For reference :

[pluck()](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-pluck)

[How to create Datagrid in Bagisto](https://bagisto.com/en/how-to-create-datagrid-in-bagisto/)

Comment: yes, this CRM is based on Bagisto, however I tried reversing the Pluck() arguments and still same thing happen, it changes the sales person to NULL

Comment: can you show `getUserDropdownOptions()` result and `$options`?

Comment: The results is a list of row numbers. means the first value is the first row of the users table. the users table has the name and the ID of the sales persons.